# Scala: Implicit evidence for class with type parameter

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, type-parameter

Here is a simple setup with two traits, a class with a covariant type parameter bounded by the previous traits, and a second class with a type parameter bounded by the other class. For both classes, a particular method is available (via implicit evidence) only if one of the two traits underlies the type parameter. This compiles fine:

```
trait Foo
trait ReadableFoo extends Foo {def field: Int}

case class Bar[+F <: Foo](foo: F) {
  def readField(implicit evidence: F <:< ReadableFoo) = foo.field
}

case class Grill[+F <: Foo, +B <: Bar[F]](bar: B) {
  def readField(implicit evidence: F <:< ReadableFoo) = bar.readField
}
```

However, since `Bar` is covariant in `F`, I shouldn't need the `F` parameter in `Grill`. I should just require that `B` is a subtype of `Bar[ReadableFoo]`. This, however, fails:

```
case class Grill[+B <: Bar[_]](bar: B) {
  def readField(implicit evidence: B <:< Bar[ReadableFoo]) = bar.readField
}
```

with the error:

```
error: Cannot prove that Any <:< this.ReadableFoo.
  def readField(implicit evidence: B <:< Bar[ReadableFoo]) = bar.readField
```

Why is the implicit evidence not being taken into account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call `bar.readField` is possible because the evidence instance `<:<` allows an implicit conversion from `B` to `Bar[ReadableFoo]`.

The problem I think that to call `readField` you need a successive evidence parameter `F <:< ReadableFoo`. So my guess is, the compiler doesn't fully substitute the type parameter of `Bar` in the first search stage of the implicit resolution (because to find `readField`, it just requires any `Bar` in the first place). And then it chokes on the second implicit resolution, because there is no form of 'backtracking' as far as I know.

Anyway. The good thing is, you know more than the compiler and you can engage the conversion explicitly, either by using the `apply` method of `<:<`, or by using the helper method `implicitly`:

```
case class Grill[+B <: Bar[_]](bar: B) {
  def readField(implicit evidence: B <:< Bar[ReadableFoo]) = evidence(bar).readField
}

case class Grill[+B <: Bar[_]](bar: B) {
  def readField(implicit evidence: B <:< Bar[ReadableFoo]) = 
    implicitly[Bar[ReadableFoo]](bar).readField
}
```

There is another possibility which might be the cleanest, as it doesn't rely on the implementation of `<:<` which might be a problem as @Kaito suggests:

```
case class Grill[+B <: Bar[_]](bar: B) {
  def readField(implicit evidence: B <:< Bar[ReadableFoo]) =
     (bar: Bar[ReadableFoo]).readField
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if <:< is meant to be called, its simply a value that exists if the first parameter is a subtype of the second. The implementation is basically the identity function.
Those examples work because they're basically doing a (safe) typecast which helps the compiler find the implicit parameter for the readField method.

Comment: @Kaito: Do you have any evidence that `<:<`'s `apply` isn't meant to be called? It's [documented behavior](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/Predef$$$less$colon$less.html). You could write `(bar: Bar[ReadableFoo]).readField` and let the implicit conversion kick in automatically, but Sciss's version feels cleaner to me.

Comment: @TravisBrown: None. But I can't find the line that actually verbally documents the behavior of the function, just the inherited explanation of the abstract Function1 trait. I agree that its nice but I'm not sure if that behavior can be relied on, it might as well throw an exception in the next version I think.

Comment: @Kaito: There is no magic or special treatment in `<:<` by the compiler. It is an implicit conversion (and therefore `apply` will be normally called); this is not a contradiction to the fact that due to the covariance of the function's return type indeed it acts as an identity function. See [the source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L412) on how `apply` works, and more importantly how the implicit is constructed (method `conforms`). So you are right, it's doing a safe typecast, but then again, this is exactly what is happening implicitly, too.

Comment: @Sciss Hm, I just don't see the type constraints as implicit conversions but I do suppose that it makes sense that they must be consistent with other conversions since they'll be found by view bounds too.

Answer (score 7):

0__'s answer (use the implicit evidence argument to turn `bar` into the right type) is the answer I'd give to the specific question you asked (although I'd suggest not using `implicitly` if you've got the implicit argument sitting right there).

It's worth noting that the situation you're describing sounds like it might be a good use case for ad-hoc polymorphism via type classes, however. Say for example that we've got the following setup:

```
trait Foo
case class Bar[F <: Foo](foo: F)
case class Grill[B <: Bar[_]](bar: B)
```

And a type class, along with some convenience methods for creating new instances and for pimping a `readField` method onto any type that has an instance in scope:

```
trait Readable[A] { def field(a: A): Int }

object Readable {
  def apply[A, B: Readable](f: A => B) = new Readable[A] {
    def field(a: A) = implicitly[Readable[B]].field(f(a))
  }

  implicit def enrich[A: Readable](a: A) = new {
    def readField = implicitly[Readable[A]].field(a)
  }
}

import Readable.enrich
```

And a couple of instances:

```
implicit def barInstance[F <: Foo: Readable] = Readable((_: Bar[F]).foo)
implicit def grillInstance[B <: Bar[_]: Readable] = Readable((_: Grill[B]).bar)
```

And finally a readable `Foo`:

```
case class MyFoo(x: Int) extends Foo

implicit object MyFooInstance extends Readable[MyFoo] {
  def field(foo: MyFoo) = foo.x
}
```

This allows us to do the following, for example:

```
scala> val readableGrill = Grill(Bar(MyFoo(11)))
readableGrill: Grill[Bar[MyFoo]] = Grill(Bar(MyFoo(11)))

scala> val anyOldGrill = Grill(Bar(new Foo {}))
anyOldGrill: Grill[Bar[java.lang.Object with Foo]] = Grill(Bar($anon$1@483457f1))

scala> readableGrill.readField
res0: Int = 11

scala> anyOldGrill.readField
<console>:22: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of
type Readable[Grill[Bar[java.lang.Object with Foo]]]
              anyOldGrill.readField
              ^
```

Which is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question, but to show that the 'type constraint' is really just an implicit conversion:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_33).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> trait A { def test() {} }
defined trait A

scala> class WhatHappens[T] { def test(t: T)(implicit ev: T <:< A) = t.test() }
defined class WhatHappens

scala> :javap -v WhatHappens
...
public void test(java.lang.Object, scala.Predef$$less$colon$less);
  Code:
   Stack=2, Locals=3, Args_size=3
   0:   aload_2
   1:   aload_1
   2:   invokeinterface #12,  2; //InterfaceMethod scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   7:   checkcast   #14; //class A
   10:  invokeinterface #17,  1; //InterfaceMethod A.test:()V
   15:  return
...
  LocalVariableTable: 
   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
   0      16      0    this       LWhatHappens;
   0      16      1    t       Ljava/lang/Object;
   0      16      2    ev       Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;
...
```

Comment: I'm aware of how it works. The question I was asking is simply whether that is intended behavior and can be relied on in future updates. The documentation mentions only that they're type constraints, not their usage as implicit conversions.